# Grails performance: XML processing 4x slower in tomcat than run-app?

Tags: performance, tomcat, grails, tomcat6

Does anyone have ideas about why a *Grails app runs **4x slower in tomcat*** (6 and 7) than  via `grails run-app`? Otherwise, I'd appreciate general advice about how I can track this down myself.

#### The situation

I've got a web app that does some fairly intensive XML processing (parsing, xpath, serialization).  For large inputs, it takes ~5 seconds to return a result when running via `grails dev run-app`).

#### 4x slower when I run the same app in tomcat6!

```
grails dev war
cp target/app.war /path/to/tomcat[6|7]/webapps
```

same app, same environment, same machine: **it takes 4x longer (20 seconds)** to respond to an identical POST.

- No errors are being logged in tomcat; just the log output I expect
- Tomcat is running in non-debug mode (Ubuntu 13.04 default settings + `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m`)
- Same Java version

---

### Update

It looks like the following runs about 12x slower in Tomcat:

```
XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath()
```

... and I was, um, calling that a lot.  Well, that's fixed now but I'd still like to know:

1. What might cause this to be so much slower in Tomcat?
2. What tools / approaches could I have taken to arrive at this discovery more easily? (I did a lot of manual debugging to figure this out.)

Comment: Java versions the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service provider mechanism determines which class is used as the implementation of XPathFactory. A JAR file on the class path that contains the file `META-INF/services/javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory` can replace the default implementation in the JRE.

Most likely, the class path is different for development and production environments in your case.

To check which implementation is used you can print `XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().getClass()`. The internal implementation in the JRE is `com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl`.